# Complex K-theory cohomology ring $K^*(T^2)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, k-theory

I was considering the complex K-theory of $T^2$ and I found, using the split exact sequences associated with the pair $(T^2,S^1 \vee S^1)$ that

$\widetilde{K}^0(T^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}$ and $\widetilde{K}^{-1}(T^2)\cong\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$,

so that one arrives at

$K^*(T^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Now my question is about the ring structure here. We know that in $K(T^2)$ we have the same ring structure as in $K(S^2)\cong \mathbb{Z}[H]/(H-1)^2$, where $H$ is the standard degree one line bundle over $S^2$, and hence we understand how to multiply some factors since the product in $K^*$ reduces to that in $K$ when multiplying degree zero elements, but I can't seem to understand how it works in general. I would appreciate any pointers on how to derive the ring structure in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take more information from the exact sequence. Indeed it tells you what $K^*(T^2)$ is but also where its elements "come from".

For instance, the sequence tells you that $\tilde K^0(S^2)\to \tilde K^0(T^2)$ induced by the quotient map $p:T^2\to S^2$ is an isomorphism.

Similarly, by Bott periodicity, this holds in all even degrees.

In odd degrees, you know that the restriction map $K^{2i+1}(T^2)\to K^{2i+1}(S^1\vee S^1)$, induced by the inclusion $i:S^1\vee S^1\to T^2$, is an isomorphism.

But both $K^*(S^2)\to K^*(T^2)$ and $K^*(T^2)\to K^*(S^1\vee S^1)$ are also ring maps.

So for instance let's take an odd degree element $x\in K^{2i+1}(T^2)$ and an even degree one, $y\in K^{2j}(T^2)$. Then $y= p^*(z)$ for some $z\in K^{2j}(S^2)$, therefore $i^*(xy) = i^*(x) i^*(p^*(z))$. Now $p\circ i$ is the constant map, so $i^*p^*$ is exactly the map induced by $S^1\vee S^1\to *\to S^2$, so if $z \in \mathbb Z[H]/(H-1)^2$, $i^*p^*(z)$ corresponds to taking the degree $0$ monomial of $z$, so it's just $i^*(x) \epsilon(z) = i^*(\epsilon(z)x)$ because $\epsilon(z)\in\mathbb Z$

But $i^*$ is an isomorphism in odd degrees, so $xy = \epsilon(z)x$. So you're fixing the isomorphism $K^{2j}(T^2)\cong \mathbb Z^2$, you forget one of the coordinates of $y$ and you multiply $x$ by that (which is an integer)

The rest of the ring structure is determined similarly : if you multiply two elements of even degree, they'll come from elements of even degree in $S^2$ and so this is entirely controlled by $K^*(S^2)$.

The last thing is what happens when you multiply two odd degree elements?

EDIT : as Tyrone pointed out, the argument I had written here does not work to compute the product of odd degree elements.

In fact, as he suggested, there is a Künneth formula, as $K^*(S^1)$ is flat over $K^*$, that gives $K^*(T^2)\cong K^*(S^1)\otimes K^*(S^1)$, as rings and this allows for a good understanding of the ring structure on $K^*(T^2)$, better than what I tried to do here.

For a reference for that Künneth formula, one can check out the references of [this nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+coefficient+theorem#ForGeneralizedCohomology), see e.g. Theorem (Boa95, 4.19) 2.12

So, to summarize :

-multiplication of even degree elements is controlled by $K^*(S^2)$

-multiplication of elements of different parity is "trivial" : if $x$ is odd and $y$ is even, then $xy = \epsilon(y)x$, where $\epsilon$ is the composite $K^*(T^2)\to K^*(\mathrm{pt})\to K^*(T^2)$

Comment: You seem to have also proved that all cup products in $H^*T^2$ are trivial...

Comment: @Tyrone : I.haven't, have I ?

Comment: Maybe not, but it seemed like you claimed that the degree $1$ elements $x=\pi_1^*(\tilde x),y=\pi_2^*(\tilde x)$ have a trivial product using only arguments that would apply to any multiplicative cohomology theory.

Comment: As far as I can see, the Kunneth formula can be used to compute $K^*(T^2)\cong K^*(S^1)\otimes K^*(S^1)$ as graded rings.

Comment: Thank you Maxime and Tyrone, this is great!

Comment: @Tyrone : Ah I think you're right I made  a mistake there. But I didn't know Künneth held on the nose for $K$-theory

Comment: There is a tor term, but of course $K^*T^2$ is torsion free.

Comment: @Tyrone : I think I'll have to read up on some $K$-theory (I actually answered this question as an exercise for myself - and apparently failed, thankfully my mistake wasn't about $K$-theory specifically - because I just started learning about it) to see where that comes from

Comment: @Tyrone : I'm not sure there's a "by hands"-way to see how odd degree elements multiply so I just removed that bit and said what you said.

Comment: So the Kunneth formula yields $K^*(T^2)\cong K^*(S^1)\otimes K^*(S^1)$. Now it seems to me that $K^*(S^1)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]/\alpha^2$, because the odd element multiplication has to go to zero since $\widetilde{K}^{2i}(S^1)=0$, right? So that would give a ring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha,\beta]/(\alpha^2,\beta^2)$. Is this it?

Comment: That can't be right, because it would mean that $K^*(S^1)$ is concentrated in degrees $0$ and $1$, which can't happen because of Bott periodicity. You're right however that odd degree elements square to $0$, because the decomposition $K^*(S^1)\cong K^*(\mathrm{pt})\oplus \tilde K^*(S^1)$ is a decomposition with $\tilde K$ as an ideal (another argument is that $x^2 = -x$ for an odd degree $x$, and $K^*(S^1)$ is torsion-free). What this means is that you have $K^*(S^1)\cong K^*(\mathrm{pt})[\alpha]/(\alpha^2), |\alpha=1|$, but of course $K^*(\mathrm{pt})$ is not $\mathbb Z$

Comment: But I think the tensor product in the Künneth formula is *over $K^*(\mathrm{pt})$*, so this description in terms of $K^*(\mathrm{pt})$ is actually better than one in terms of $\mathbb Z$, because you indeed get $K^*(\mathrm{pt})[\alpha,\beta]/(\alpha^2,\beta^2)$

Comment: Ah right I just checked something out : it depends on what kind of ring you're considering : if you're considering $\mathbb Z/2$-graded rings, then you're completely right - I was thinking in terms of $\mathbb Z$-graded rings

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-grading. Thank you! I still don't understand why your previous argument in odd degree multiplication fails. As I recall, you decomposed odd degree elements of $K^*(T^2)$ as $x=x_0+x_1$, where $x_i=\pi^{*}_i\widetilde{x}_i$. I though the products which involved projections $\pi^*_0$ and $\pi^{*}_1$ would be zero because they would vanish along the projections onto $\widetilde{K}^{-1}(S^1)$ in the decomposition $\widetilde{K}^{-1}(S^1\vee S^1)=\widetilde{K}^{-1}(S^1)\oplus \widetilde{K}^{-1}(S^1)$

Comment: The problem is that their product vanishes in $S^1$, but in even degree (the product of odd degree elements has even degree, of course). So you get $i_0^*(\pi_0^*(\tilde x_0) \pi_1^*(\tilde x_1)) = 0$, indeed, and same with $i_1^*$, but $i^*$ is *not* an isomorphism in even degree (or in degree $0$, with your convention of grading)

Comment: Very nice! That clears it out -- thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome, sorry about the mistake !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111234/discussion-between-b-mera-and-maxime-ramzi).